# Meta Description and Keywords in SharePoint 2013

Tags: keywords, meta-description, sharepoint

Should I fill Meta Description only or Meta Description and Keywords in SharePoint 2013 SEO Properties?

I heard Google and other search engines don't look at the Keywords anymore.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, keywords can be omitted. But the description shows in the search, around 160 characters. So you should provide short summary of the page in the description.